# Rails: Multiple Joins with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord

I have a model of `Athlete`

AthleteModel:

```
class Athlete < User
  has_many :videos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :stats, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I am trying to find all videos and stats for an athlete where the `created_at` fields (respectively for each association) is less than or equal to a week old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know how stats and videos are related together, I would do:

```
# athlete.rb
def get_videos_and_stats
  videos = Video.where(athlete_id: self, created_at: 1.week.ago..Date.today)
  stats = Stat.where(athlete_id: self, created_at: 1.week.ago..Date.today)

  [videos, stats] # returns an array containing both videos and stats
end

# athletes_controller.rb
def show
  @athlete = Athlete.find(params[:id])
  # makes two instance variables and assign videos and stats to them
  @videos, @stats = athlete.get_videos_and_stats
end

# athletes/show.html.erb
<%= render @videos %>
<%= render @stats %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I had to change `Date.today` to `Time.now` but it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The following should work too, if I understood you right:

```
Athlete.includes(
  :videos, :stats
).where(
  'athletes.id = :athlete_id and videos.created_at <= :week_ago and stats.created_at <= :week_ago', 
   athlete_id: 1, week_ago: 1.week.ago.end_of_day)
```